# How to run resque-scheduler in production with remote DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm finding this hard to figure out as.

I'm deploying using Capistrano, and I have quite a few recurring scheduled tasks that I'm using resque-scheduler to run.

On my local environment I would run:

```
QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
```

to start resque and to start resque-scheduler:

```
rake environment resque:scheduler
```

this is my resque.rake file:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDIS_SERVER']
  end
  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
  end

  task :scheduler_setup => :setup_schedule
end
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is how I get this working in production? I assume I first need to install redis on my server even though I have a remote Redis DB? Then I need to make a capistrano task, or something that make it run?

Answer (score 0):

1. To connect to remote redis replace `Resque.redis` value with

   uri = URI.parse('redis://redistogo_url:9918/')
   Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
2. You don't need to install `redis' server just the normal gem